# how to create hashtag for a gerrit cahnge from ssh?

Tags: gerrit, hashtag

I wanted to create hashtag using ssh gerrit command.
Example: i tried below

```
ssh -p 22 server.com gerrit  set-reviewers --add  "#bugfix" 123455
```

its giving error account bugfix not found

also tried , --addhashtag, saying no such option.

gerrit query on gerrit webpage search working with

```
hashtag:NAME
```

but not finding way to apply tag from automations, don't want to go for curl commands or API.

tried all options from chatGPT

Answer (score 0):

You can't add hashtags using the "gerrit set-reviewers" command, use the API to do that instead:

```
curl --user USER:PASS --request POST  --data @- --header Content-Type:application/json https://GERRIT-SERVER/a/changes/CHANGE-NUMBER/hashtags << EOF
{
    "add": [ "bugfix" ]
}
```

See more information in Gerrit documentation [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api-changes.html#set-hashtags).